# Move file depending on row count of csv file

Tags: c#, sql-server, csv, ssis

I have a SSIS package which has a single .csv file as a flat file source.  A conditional split inserts the data in various SQL Server staging tables based on an ID.  Any rows that do not successfully insert are then redirected to an error .csv file, one per ID.

With these numerous error files, I want to perform an evaluation on the number of rows there are (apart from the header row).  If there is at least one data error row, these will be sent via a send email task to the source developers, otherwise they will be archived via File System task.

I'm struggling on how to approach this.  I have some idea that a Foreach loop container in the error file directory could be used to loop through and perform a row count via script task.  However, I'm not sure how I can pass the individual file names to the script task.  Furthermore, I'm not sure afterwards I can do the conditional email/file system task move.

In terms of script tasking, I've got something that looks like this (it errors) for the script task, failure being it's not more than 1 and gets archived, pass it gets emailed, just for some idea.  I'm fairly new with complex C# scripting.

```
        public void Main()
        {
        string folderPath = Dts.Variables["User::errorDirectory"].Value.ToString();
        string archivePath = @"\\SERVER\placeholderfilepath\blah\blah";
        var FileNames = new List<string>();
        var FilePaths = new List<string>();

        DirectoryInfo directoryInfo = new DirectoryInfo(folderPath);
        FileInfo[] files = directoryInfo.GetFiles();

        var lineCount = 0;


        foreach (FileInfo fileInfo in files)
        {

            lineCount = File.ReadAllLines(fileInfo.FullName).Count();

            //MessageBox.Show(lineCount.ToString());

            if (lineCount == 1)
            {
                File.Move(folderPath, archivePath);
            }

        }




       Dts.TaskResult = (int)ScriptResults.Success;

       }
```

After a few hours of searching I can't find anything that covers this, so would be grateful for any pointers / articles.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You might try adding Row Count component to the data flow that writes the data to .CSV. Row Count will put the number of rows to some variable and then you'll know if there were any rows in .CSV

I can see the problem in your code

```
string folderPath = Dts.Variables["User::errorDirectory"].Value.ToString();
        string archivePath = @"\\SERVER\placeholderfilepath\blah\blah";
        var FileNames = new List<string>();
        var FilePaths = new List<string>();

        DirectoryInfo directoryInfo = new DirectoryInfo(folderPath);
        FileInfo[] files = directoryInfo.GetFiles();

        var lineCount = 0;


        foreach (FileInfo fileInfo in files)
        {

            lineCount = File.ReadAllLines(fileInfo.FullName).Count();

            //MessageBox.Show(lineCount.ToString());

            if (lineCount == 1) 
            {
                File.Move(fileInfo.FullName, Path.Combine(archivePath, fileInfo.Name));
            }

        }

        Dts.TaskResult = (int)ScriptResults.Success;
```

Comment: I had considered this, but I wanted to know if it could be done more efficiently via script than setting up numerous row count variables.  There will be 10 of these files to start and I am expecting the number to increase over time, so want to make this future-proof.

Comment: Have considered having a loop over these ID values? In this case the same flow will be reused for all IDs. Or you want to send single email with all error .CSVs?

Comment: What I really want is an evaluation of each file in a directory. If RowCount is  > 1, leave the file there, otherwise move it to an archive folder.  I want to loop over each file in the directory, open it, perform a row count to do this.  The mail task will just pick up the files that have not been moved, so it's not a problem with that bit.  What I am struggling with is some scripting to read each package variable for the file name, count the rows and decide whether or not to archive it.

Comment: Sorry, I mean I want it to read each file in the directory, which will be passed to the script via variable.

Comment: Sure, then you probably might go on with the script task. I fixed your code slightly. Try it now, please

Comment: No longer gets a compile error, however does appear to be stuck in an infinite loop.

Comment: Oh sure))) reader.Read() != null is always true)))) I fixed the loop.

Comment: Thanks for your help so far.  Nearly there.  If you see my original question, I have amended my code based on yours.  Yours will work and row count correctly, I tested it with the commented-out MessageBox.Show().  Can you see that in the foreach loop I am trying to move the file to an archive location if the lineCount is 1?  This is throwing a compilation error, any thoughts?

Comment: I fixed your File.Move method call. Try now, please

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/122210/discussion-between-karpukhin-olexiy-and-tjb).

Comment: Thank you, objective complete :) Really very grateful for your help.

Answer (score 1):

Instead of a ForEach loop to count the files, just handle everything in the script task.   Use the `filesystemobject` to get the collection of files in the folder, and use the count property of the collection.

Comment: Thanks for commenting... however it's the row count of each file in the directory, not just the count of the files.

Comment: Ok, well you can still skip the foreach loop and do everything in the script.  Or if you want to pass file names from a loop to a script, you would use a package variable.

Comment: I should also mention, the files are produced every day and the file name changes dynamically with each day (via a package variable for each error file).

Comment: That doesn't matter, either way you do it.